# How do multiple clients communicate using messaging system? (Python)

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, chat, message

I have a server listening to all the clients that are connected to it, and each client should have this "username" they are identified by, but I'm stuck here... when a client wants to send a message to another client, they send the other client's username as the first word in the message sent to the server. Then I wouldn't know how to direct the message to the right socket (the receiving client). How should I link a client to its socket?? so I can call socket.send??

I'm currently modifying the code from this website:  http://www.binarytides.com/code-chat-application-server-client-sockets-python/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def broadcast_data (sock, message):
    #Do not send the message to master socket and the client who has send us the message
    for socket in CONNECTION_LIST:
        if socket != server_socket and socket != sock :
            try :
                socket.send(message)
            except :
                # broken socket connection may be, chat client pressed ctrl+c for example
                socket.close()
                CONNECTION_LIST.remove(socket)
```

This function could be used as a starting point for a send function

```
def send_data (sock, message):
    #send message to only one client
    #sock is the socket of the client to send to
    try :
      sock.send(message)
    except :
      # broken socket connection may be, chat client pressed ctrl+c for example
      sock.close()
      CONNECTION_LIST.remove(socket)
```

then you could have a dictionary of sockets associating them with a user name

```
usernameSockets={}
usernameSockets[username]=socket_for_user_name
```

then you could call the send_data function like

```
send_data(usernameSockets[username],message)
```

In the code you linked to there is no method for getting a username so you would have to have the clients send their username to the server when they are connecting to be able to populate a dictionary like the one I have mentioned above.